# Importing mysql script file in different version

Tags: mysql

Currently, I am using mysql version 5.0.45 - community-nt. I have created tables in that database. After that, I export the script file from and I imported other mysql server. That version is 5.5.29. In my tables, there is BIT datatype. When I imported my exported data to other mysql version, the imported data are changed. Imported data are not correct. So, How shall I handle.

Comment: I used the phpmyadmin for exporting and importing. Is that relate to phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

If you're exporting with the `mysqldump` command you can use the `--compatible` option. For some reason there isn't a `mysql50` option but you can use `mysql40` and it should work for you:

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword -hyour.host \
  --compatible=mysql40 your_database > your_database.sql
```

Comment: Thank. When I did as your command, the tables are TYPE=InnoDB. But in version 5.5.29 tables are ENGINE=InnoDB. I think command is not export for version 5.5. So, how shall I manage?

Comment: Did you try importing the resulting file?